# Find/store the first 50 terms of the Fibonacci sequence via Looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying find and store the first 50 elements of the Fibonacci Sequence into an array by looping.  I am quite new to Python and I can't get past this point, I am very frustrated that I can't figure out how to do this.

My code so far:

```py
x=51
 def Fibonacci(x):
    First_Value=0
    Second_Value=1
    for i in range(x):
        Next_value = First_Value
        First_Value = Second_Value
        Second_Value = Next_value + Second_Value
    return Fist_Value"
```

But I can't figure out how to print this in an array where I have to show the first 50 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be modified to return an array.

```py
def Fibonacci(x):
   First_Value=0
   Second_Value=1
   Result = []
   for i in range(x):
       Next_value = First_Value
       First_Value = Second_Value
       Second_Value = Next_value + Second_Value
       Result.append(Next_value)
   return Result

print(Fibonacci(20))
```

Output:

> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181]

Answer (score 3):

You can define an empty list (or array) at the beginning of the function, and then add to it on every iteration of the for loop.

Here's an example

```
def Fibonacci(x):
    fib_array = [None]*x
    First_Value=0
    Second_Value=1
    for i in range(x):
        Next_value = First_Value
        First_Value = Second_Value
        Second_Value = Next_value + Second_Value
        fib_array[i] = First_Value
    return fib_array

Fibonacci(10)
```

Output

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

Comment: I think it would be more common to start with an empty array and then append the next 50 values to it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you alrady know how to generate Fibonacci numbers then one solution is to simply generate an array out of your predefined function:

```py
result = [Fibonacci(x) for x in range(51)]
```

but this is awefuly inefficient (you recalculate Fibonacci numbers all the time). You can improve it by tweaking your function:

```py
def Fibonacci(x):
    if x < 0:
        raise ValueError("Argument has to be a nonnegative integer")
    if x == 0:
        return []
    if x == 1:
        return [0]
    result = [0, 1]
    for _ in range(x-2, 0, -1):
        result.append(result[-1] + result[-2])
    return result

print(Fibonacci(51))
```